# Trying to install packages in Laravel 5

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.1

I was trying to install the package of `HOA/Websockets` in my Laravel 5 website,

from following link

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/hoawebsocket-with-laravel-5-projects-push-notifications

But when I added the

```
"require": {
        "hoa/websocket": "~2.0"
    }
```

In my composer and ran

```
composer install
```

But in my command prompt it says nothing to be installed. Can any one help me out with this, Please?

Also when I try to do

`composer require "hoa/websocket": "~2.0"`

it is uninstalling some of the packages and not installing it back.

Comment: did you try to delete the `vendor` folder and run `composer install` again? Sometimes this helps in such cases.

Comment: If you're adding it manually to the composer.json file then try `composer update` instead.

Comment: @James yeah I did that and now I am getting following error '
Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in D:\ide-invoi
ce\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an
error'

Answer (score 1):

Well I fixed it this way

Just copied the new package that was installed inside the Vendor folder which was vendors/HOA,

Then I pasted in my older backup of the vendor folder and pasted it back inside my website and VOILA!! it works

Hope it helps some one needy 
Thanks